# Data in my component will show only after clicks on screen ( Angular )

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, components, bootstrap-5

I'm creating a calendar and i want to pass some events and show them on it. I was testing with some hardcoded events and everything was fine. Now i'm taking these events from a springboot application who communicates with a database and i have this problem. When i open the calendar i can't see the events on it but i can see them in the console.log . If i click in a random spot the events will correctly show on the calendar.

This is my calendar.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  styleUrls: [],
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',

})

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit{

  incompleteEvents: any;
  events: CalendarEvent[] = new Array

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: SpringbootService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.getEventi(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('email')!)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.incompleteEvents = data

       for (let i = 0; i < this.incompleteEvents.length; i++) {

         const newEvent = {
          start: new Date(this.incompleteEvents[i].start.dateTime),
          end: new Date(this.incompleteEvents[i].end.dateTime),
          title: this.incompleteEvents[i].subject,

         }

         this.events.push(newEvent)
       }

       console.log(this.events)

    })
  }

  view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;

  CalendarView = CalendarView;

  viewDate: Date = new Date();

  refresh = new Subject<void>();

  activeDayIsOpen: boolean = false;

  dayClicked({date, events}: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
    if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
      this.activeDayIsOpen = !((isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen) ||
        events.length === 0);
      this.viewDate = date;
    }
  }

  addEvent(): void {
    this.events = [
      ...this.events,
      {
        title: 'New event',
        start: startOfDay(new Date()),
      },
    ];
  }

  deleteEvent(eventToDelete: CalendarEvent) {
    this.events = this.events.filter((event) => event !== eventToDelete);
  }

  setView(view: CalendarView) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  closeOpenMonthViewDay() {
    this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
  }
}
```

this is the html:

```
<div style="margin: 2% 5%;">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div style="float: left"
           class="btn btn-primary"
      ><a style="color: white" routerLink="/">
        Back
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <div
          class="btn btn-primary"
          mwlCalendarPreviousView
          [view]="view"
          [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
          (viewDateChange)="closeOpenMonthViewDay()"
        >
          Previous
        </div>
        <div
          class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          mwlCalendarToday
          [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
        >
          Today
        </div>
        <div
          class="btn btn-primary"
          mwlCalendarNextView
          [view]="view"
          [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
          (viewDateChange)="closeOpenMonthViewDay()"
        >
          Next
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'en' }}</b></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <div
          class="btn btn-primary"
          (click)="setView(CalendarView.Month)"
          [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Month"
        >
          Month
        </div>
        <div
          class="btn btn-primary"
          (click)="setView(CalendarView.Week)"
          [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Week"
        >
          Week
        </div>
        <div
          class="btn btn-primary"
          (click)="setView(CalendarView.Day)"
          [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Day"
        >
          Day
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div [ngSwitch]="view">
    <mwl-calendar-month-view
      *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [events]="events"
      [refresh]="refresh"
      [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
      (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
    >
    </mwl-calendar-month-view>
    <mwl-calendar-week-view
      *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [events]="events"
      [refresh]="refresh"
    >
    </mwl-calendar-week-view>
    <mwl-calendar-day-view
      *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Day"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [events]="events"
      [refresh]="refresh"
    >
    </mwl-calendar-day-view>
  </div>

  <h3>
    <b style="margin-left: 8px">Edit events</b>
    <button class="btn btn-primary float-end" (click)="addEvent()" style="margin-top: 5px;">
      Add new
    </button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </h3>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Starts at</th>
        <th>Ends at</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let event of events">
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="event.title"
            (keyup)="refresh.next()"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            mwlFlatpickr
            [(ngModel)]="event.start"
            (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()"
            [altInput]="true"
            [convertModelValue]="true"
            [enableTime]="true"
            dateFormat="Y-m-dTH:i"
            altFormat="F j, Y H:i"
            placeholder="Not set"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            mwlFlatpickr
            [(ngModel)]="event.end"
            (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()"
            [altInput]="true"
            [convertModelValue]="true"
            [enableTime]="true"
            dateFormat="Y-m-dTH:i"
            altFormat="F j, Y H:i"
            placeholder="Not set"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEvent(event)">
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console when doing this?

Comment: Pushing new events to the array doesn't trigger the change detection mechanism. Add this events to the array like in the `addEvent` method.

Comment: @derstauner do you mean in the OnInit() ? What should i write ?

Comment: F. e. create a copy of the `events` array (or an empty array), push the events to this array and then assign this array to the `events` array.